# MySQL Error 1109 caused by Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables in this database; two of which are involved with this trigger

```
create table shipment_item(
    shipmentID int not null,
    shipmentItemID int not null,
    purchaseID int not null,
    insuredValue decimal(5,2) not null,
    constraint shipment_ItemPK primary key(shipmentID, shipmentItemID),
    constraint shipmentFK foreign key(shipmentID)
            references shipment(shipmentID)
            on delete cascade,
    constraint purchaseFK foreign key(purchaseID)
            references purchase(purchaseID)
);

create table purchase(
    purchaseID int not null auto_increment, 
    storeID int not null,
    purchaseDate date not null,
    description char(30) not null,
    category char(30) not null,
    price decimal(5,2) not null,
    constraint purchasePK primary key(purchaseID),
    constraint storeFK foreign key(storeID)
            references store(storeID)
);
```

I'm trying to implement a trigger in my MySQL database. That trigger looks like this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER checkInsuranceTrigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON shipment_item
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF(shipment_item.insuredValue <= purchase.price) THEN
    SET NEW.insuredValue = purchase.price;
  END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

When I implement this trigger and then try to insert data into the shipment_item table I get the following error

Error Code 1109: Unknown Table 'shipment_item' in field list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the column in the row being inserted with the **`NEW`** keyword, like you did on the SET statement.

To reference values from rows in other tables, you need a SQL statement, in your case, looks like you want a SELECT.

For example (following the outline of the logic in your trigger), something like this:

```
BEGIN
   -- local variable
   DECLARE ln_purchase_price DECIMAL(5,2);

   -- populate local variable (this is just an example of one way to do this)
   SELECT p.price
     INTO ln_purchase_price
     FROM purchase p
    WHERE p.purchaseID = NEW.purchaseID
    LIMIT 1;

   -- compare value from row to local variable
   IF (NEW.insuredValue <= ln_purchase_price) THEN
      SET NEW.insuredValue = ln_purchase_price;
   END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest verifying that the table really exists **in the same database** as the trigger itself?

Comment: It does, in MySQL Workbench it is listed in the proper place

Comment: However, I'd try to call the table shipment_item by its full name (e.g., db.shipment_item) in the trigger's body.